# Django: Test client's context is empty from the shell

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing

I cannot access the `context` attribute of an `HttpResponse` object from ipython. But the unit test accesses `context`.

Here is the unit test. The test run passes properly:

```
from django.test import Client, TestCase
from django.core import mail

class ClientTest(TestCase):
    def test_get_view(self):
        data = {'var': u'\xf2'}
        response = self.client.get('/test04/', data)

        # Check some response details
        self.assertContains(response, 'This is a test')
        self.assertEqual(response.context['var'], u'\xf2')
```

Here is the code that I used in the shell:

```
In [10]: from django.test import Client

In [11]: c = Client()

In [12]: r = c.get('/test04/', data)

In [13]: r.context

In [14]: type(r.context)
Out[14]: <type 'NoneType'>
```

`response.context` is none in the shell whereas `response.context` exists in the unit test.

Why does `HttpResponse` behave inconsistently between the shell and unit test?

Comment: I tried this myself and neither context nor template is set in Django shell. I guess Client is not intended to be used in an interactive shell. Test runner makes some instrumentation before running tests, which won't get triggered via shell. See `django.test.testcases`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see in the Django test code where it monkeypatches in special instrumentation to [make template rendering send a signal](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/test/utils.py?rev=11917#L24), which the [test client listens to](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/test/client.py?rev=11917#L224) so it can [annotate the response object with the rendered templates and their contexts](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/test/client.py?rev=11917#L254).

For this signal to be attached, you'd have to either call the django.test.utils.setup_test_environment() function in your shell session (which has other side effects), or duplicate just the lines that monkeypatch template rendering. Not too hard, but I agree it'd be nice if this particular debugging aspect could be refactored out to make it easier to use outside of tests. Personally I wouldn't mind if this information was always collected when DEBUG is True, not just under test.