# Django unit test client response has empty context

Tags: python, django, django-unittest

I have a unit test that's failing in an assertion that passes in another test in the same test case class.

Here's the passing test:

```
def test_home(self):
    c = Client()
    resp = c.get('/')
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
    self.assertTrue('a_formset' in resp.context)
```

Here's the failing test:

```
def test_number_initial_number_of_forms(self):
    c = Client()
    resp = c.get('/')
    self.assertEqual(resp.context['a_formset'].total_form_count(), 1)
```

In the second test, I get the error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`.

If I execute the second test as

```
def test_number_initial_number_of_forms(self):
    c = Client()
    resp = c.get('/')
    self.assertTrue('a_formset' in resp.context)
    self.assertEqual(resp.context['a_formset'].total_form_count(), 1)
```

I get the error `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`. I've confirmed via print statements in the second test that the response.content contains the page I expect to get, that the status code is correct, and that the template is correct. But the response's context is consistently `None` in the second test.

I'm running my Django unit tests through the standard "python manage.py test ..." interface, so I don't believe I'm running into the "[context is empty from the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932706/django-test-clients-context-is-empty-from-the-shell)" issue.

What's going on with this?

**Edit:**

If I add `print type(resp.context['a_formset'])` to each test, for the working test I get `<class 'django.forms.formsets.AFormFormSet'>`. For the non-working test, I get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` again.

Comment: @sneawo Yeah, it's a formset.

Comment: In both your working and non-working tests, temporarily add the line `print type(resp.context['a_formset'])`. You might not be getting what you're expecting.

Comment: @EvanPorter Added the results of that to the question. Predictably (and unfortunately), I got the object for the working test and the missing attribute error for the non-working test. :-/

Comment: Strange that context would be None if the template has successfully rendered using that context.  PyCharm supports debugging Django tests, I would use this tool and stick a breakpoint at the end of your view, in any middleware that has a process_response() hook, and any template context processors that you may have added, tracking the context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Today I run into the same issue. The **second** test gets same page has nothing in response.context

I made a research and found that 
1) test client uses signals to populate context,
2) my view method is not called for the second test

I turned on a debugger and found that the guilty one is 'Cache middleware'. Knowing that I found [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15142) and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219668/using-django-cache-middleware-causes-contrib-auth-unit-tests-to-fail) (the latter has a solution).

**So, in short:** the second request is served from cache, not from a view, thus a view is not executed and test-client doesn't get the signal and have no ability to populate context.

I can not disable cache middleware for my project, so I added next hack-lines into my settings:

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
   CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 0
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 9):

It's because you ran into some error, exited the shell and restarted it.

But you **forgot to start environment**...

```
from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment
>>> setup_test_environment()
```

That was my problem. Hope it works...

Answer (score 1):

You can also clear cache manually by calling cache.clear() inside a test method:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
import pytest


class TestPostView:

    @pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
    def test_index_post(self, client, post):
        cache.clear()
        response = client.get('/')
```