# Django Unit Testing testing views

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I am testing my views using Django Unit testing. I am making `get` and `post` requests with params to check what status i get back.

But the problem how to check for context variables which are retuned in the response? 
For example, on the `View Cities` page, I make a get request, the `context dict` in the view has the variable `cities`. So I want to check for context.

```
         resp = self.client.post(
                path=reverse('upload_video'),
                data={"video_url": video_url, "pro": 1}
            )
            self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```

Condition is `True` both ways, if the form is invalid or valid it returns 200. If I can check for context, then I can check what has been retuned from the view in response.

### What I tried

```
=> resp.__dict__
 {'templates': [], '_handler_class': None, '_headers': {'vary': ('Vary', 'Cookie'), 'content-type': ('Content-Type', 'application/json')}, '_charset': 'utf-8', '_closable_objects': [], 'cookies': <SimpleCookie: >, 'client': <django.test.client.Client object at 0x112bace10>, '_base_content_is_iter': False, 'context': None, 'request': {u'CONTENT_LENGTH': 202, u'wsgi.input': <django.test.client.FakePayload object at 0x113667990>, u'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST', u'PATH_INFO': '/upload/video/modal/', u'CONTENT_TYPE': u'multipart/form-data; boundary=BoUnDaRyStRiNg', u'QUERY_STRING': ''}, '_container': ['{"error": {"msg": "Pro: Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.", "head": null}}']}
```

Check `_container` has that variable. The form is invalidated, and retuned an error in the context. but when I do the following i get `None`

```
=> resp.context 
   None
```

### Test

```
import os

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from django.test import TestCase 

def test_video_upload(self):
    """ Test that video upload is successful  """
    self.create_and_login(username="su", password="su", is_superuser=True)
    video_urls = [
        u"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc",
        u"https://vimeo.com/32222",
        u"http://www.dailymotion.com/video/rer"
    ]
    for video_url in video_urls:
        resp = self.client.post(
            path=reverse('upload_video'),
            data={"video_url": video_url, "pro": 1}
        )

        set_trace() #Breakpoint
        a = resp.context[-1] # <=== Not getting it here.
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200) #passes

    videos = Video.objects.all()
    self.assertEqual(len(videos), 3)
```

### View

```
ctx = {}
    if request.method == Enums.Request.POST:
        video_form = UploadVideoEasyForm(data=request.POST)
        if video_form.is_valid():
            video, log = video_form.save(request=request)
            msg = 'Successfully Uploaded, View: <a href="{}">here</a>'.format(video.get_absolute_url())
            ctx[Enums.ResponseAlert.Success] = {'msg': msg}
        else:
            ctx[Enums.ResponseAlert.Error] = make_alert(msg=form_error_to_string(video_form))
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ctx), content_type="application/json")

    elif request.method == Enums.Request.GET:
        ctx['upload_video'] = UploadVideoEasyForm()
        if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.is_superuser:
            return render_to_response('new/modals/upload_video.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request, ctx))
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The `resp` (An instance of [`django.test.Response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#testing-responses)) should have an [`context`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Response.context) attribute.

You can access context value using `context[..]`:

```
self.assertEqual(resp.context['cities'], ...)
```

Comment: @Clayton, What do you get if you do this? `resp.context[Enums.ResponseAlert.Success]` OR `resp.context[Enums.ResponseAlert.Error]`

Comment: `resp.context` is None, so I am surely will get error on this one. I am thinking more abstract?

Comment: Here what i got `*** TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: @Clayton, How about this? `resp.context_data`

Comment: Wired. `*** AttributeError: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'context_data'`

Comment: @Clayton, Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392537/django-unit-test-client-response-has-empty-context