# django unit test client response has empty request

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.1

in my test I do:

```
self.client.get('/')
```

in my template I access:

```
request.LANGUAGE_CODE
```

in the browser it works fine with the Django client I get

```
Failed lookup for key [LANGUAGE_CODE] in ''
```

From the output I believe that the request is not set in the client.

[Similar Issue that didn't help me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392537/django-unit-test-client-response-has-empty-context)

Comment: `LANGUAGE_CODE` is a settings.py configuration. Why do you do a key lookup for such a key in the request in the first place?

Comment: request.LANGUAGE_CODE yields 'en' for my .com pages and 'de' for my german pages. This way I link to different sources for each language.

Comment: @Adelin Do you see a better way to do this?

Comment: ok maybe I don't understand the question/problem then (it's not clear what's happening and at what time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error myself:

The test client was working just fine.
Some of the sites were really not working.

In my *views.py* I had the following bug:

wrong code:

`return render(some_other_view, 'page.html')`

correct code:

`return render(request, 'page.html')`